# Change Python's default logic when comparing strings

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, math, symbols

Is there any way I can make Python "think" that 5 > 6, or that some other arbitrary math/string equation is interpreted in a specific way?

I mainly want to take a string with a symbol and automatically make it larger than the other, so that `"⇟" > "◈"` evaluates to `True`.

I know you can assign these symbols to numbers, but if there is an easier way to do this, it could be more efficient.

This is a basic idea of what I want:

```
firstSymbol = input("Type in a symbol: ")
secondSymbol = input("Type in a second symbol: ")
if firstSymbol > secondSymbol:
    print("firstSymbol > secondSymbol")
elif secondSymbol > firstSymbol:
    print("secondSymbol > firstSymbol")
elif firstSymbol == secondSymbol:
    print("Your two symbols are equal")
```

Since Python already has something like this programmed in, I want to change it so that I can create my own symbols that are either greater than or less than the other symbol, without the interruption of Python's automatic string comparisons.

Comment: I can't fathom what you're hoping to accomplish this way. And what is "the turtle.py", and what does it have to do with math?

Comment: `I am trying to make my own math equations without the interruption of python` ... looks like without the interruption of _math_ :) can you edit your question to include what you're trying to do more broadly? This might be an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: I assume you cannot wrap your values with a user-defined class, right? Like `CustomInt(5) > CustomInt(6) is True`.

Comment: Is there something more general you're trying to achieve here? Is there any reason you can't just reverse the operators? I.e. `5 < 6 == True` and `"a" < "the" == True`?

Comment: Python has many ways to hack parts of it functionality either globally or only for a given module / function.
You can do monkeypatching, you can use the mock library. 
For own data types you can define your own operators.
But if you do not give a concrete example code snippet and explain what you would like to achieve exactly you will probably not get an answer that will help you solve your problem

Comment: I don't know why you're trying to do this, but this is a fun blog post https://kate.io/blog/2017/08/22/weird-python-integers/

Comment: This question was closed due to its lack of information and not identifying what was needed to be accomplished. After some careful consideration, I edited my question to fulfill these purposes. Please vote to reopen this question if you have over 3000 reputation. Thank you!

Comment: @Matt I know the question is closed now (I voted to reopen), but take a look at my edited answer and see if it helps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is fairly simple if you define your own integer class:

```
class BadInteger(int):
    def __gt__(self, other):
        return super().__lt__(other)

print(BadInteger(5) > BadInteger(6))  # prints True
```

The `BadInteger` class is based on the `int` class (i.e. the regular Python integer). But in this case, we reversed how a "greater than" comparison works by reimplementing the `__gt__` special method ("gt" stands for "greater than"). The implementation simply calls the integer's implementation of `__lt__` ("less than").

This effectively means that, when we try to compare two `BadInteger`s using `>`, it will work as if we compared two regular integers with `<`. If the "greater than" comparson would evaluate to `True` with regular integers, it will now evaluate to `False` with our `BadInteger` class, and vice-versa.

You still need to reimplement any other relevant methods, so that they work the opposite way (e.g., `__ge__` for the "greater than or equal" operator (`>=`), `__lt__` for "less than" (`<`), etc). But this sets the base to achieve what you want.

#### Edit

Since you edited your original question, here's a follow-up answer.

We can once again define a custom class in order to implement the functionality you want. Consider this:

```
class MySymbol:
    def __init__(self, symbol, value = None):
        if len(symbol) != 1:
            raise ValueError('Symbol string must have length 1')
        if value is None:
            value = ord(symbol)

        self.symbol = symbol
        self.value = value

    def __str__(self):
        return self.symbol

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'MySymbol(symbol={self.symbol}, value={self.value})'

    def __gt__(self, other):
        self.check_instance(other=other)
        return self.value > other.value

    def __ge__(self, other):

        self.check_instance(other=other)
        return self.value >= other.value

    def __eq__(self, other):
        self.check_instance(other=other)
        return self.value == other.value

    def check_instance(self, other):
        if not isinstance(other, MySymbol):
            error_message = (
               f"'==' not supported between instances of"
               f" '{self.__class__.__name__}' and"
               f" '{other.__class__.__name__}'"
            )
            raise TypeError(error_message)
```

The `MySymbol` class takes a symbol and an optional value as the input. You may have seen where this is going, but the symbol represents your string, and the value is a number used in comparisons.

Since we have implementations for the `__gt__`, `__ge__` and `__eq__` magic methods, our symbols "know" how to be compared to one another with the `>`, `>=` and `==` operators, respectively.

Additionally, Python is smart enough to re-use these implementations and simply flip the result around - so we also get `<`, `<=` and `!=` for free.

Now this might not be *exactly* what you hoped for, because we still have to inform what is the specific value of each symbol we create. But this is the price to pay when creating a custom comparison - at some point in your program, you're gonna have to declare which of your custom symbols is greater than the rest, and vice-versa. Python won't ever "just know" that you're trying to compare things in an unusual fashion without you ever telling Python that you want to do so.

Quick demo:

```
firstSymbol = MySymbol('w', 30)
secondSymbol = MySymbol('$', 108)

firstSymbol != secondSymbol
# True

firstSymbol > secondSymbol
# False

# Note that it will use Python's default string values if we don't provide one
thirdSymbol = MySymbol('a')
fourthSymbol = MySymbol('b')

thirdSymbol > fourthSymbol  # same as comparing 'a' > 'b'
# False
```

And following your example:

```
s1 = input("Type in a symbol: ")
v1_text = input("Type in its value: ")
try:
    v1 = int(v1_text)
except ValueError:  # use default string value
    v1 = None

s2 = input("Type in a second symbol: ")
v2_text = input("Type in its value: ")
try:
    v2 = int(v2_text)
except ValueError:  # use default string value
    v2 = None

firstSymbol = MySymbol(s1, v1)
secondSymbol = MySymbol(s2, v2)

if firstSymbol > secondSymbol:
    print("firstSymbol > secondSymbol")
elif secondSymbol > firstSymbol:
    print("secondSymbol > firstSymbol")
elif firstSymbol == secondSymbol:
    print("Your two symbols are equal")
```

Example output:

```
Type in a symbol: !
Type in its value: 100
Type in a second symbol: #
Type in its value: 10
firstSymbol > secondSymbol
```